# Расставить 26 латинских слов в соответствии латинскому алфавиту из 26 букв (одно слово - одна буква)

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Нам даны 26 латинских слов и соответственно латинский алфавит из 26 букв. Вывести true, если возможно расставить все слова в соответствии букве, которую оно имеет (одно слово - одна буква и должен быть затронут весь алфавит), иначе false. Например, есть слова "с", "bc" и "ab", Значит, буквам a b и с можно соответственно отнести слова "ab", "bc" и "c".

Comment: Пробегаете по словам, собираете в std::set первые буквы. `return s.size() == 26;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Построить двудольный граф, одна доля которого содержит слова, вторая - алфавит, а ребра соединяют каждое слово с содержащимися в нём буквами.

Построить максимальное паросочетание (в данном случае оно должно быть совершенным, т.е. все узлы задействованы)

Подойдёт, например, [алгоритм Куна](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching) или [алгоритм Форда-Фалкерсона](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), оба работают за O(VE)

Comment: спасибо за помощь